# Operator $Au(t) = \int_0^t e^{t-s} u(s) ds$ (Proof Verification)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification

Consider the space $C([0,1])$ with $||\cdot||_\infty$ norm. Let $A: C([0,1])\rightarrow C([0,1])$ be the operator defined by 
$$Au(t) = \int_0^t e^{t-s} u(s) ds.$$

And I am not 100% sure about **(c)**, thanks!

**(a)** Show $A$ is continuous and determine its norm.

Since $A$ is linear, it suffices to show $A$ is continuous at $0$. Let $\epsilon$ be given, define $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{e}$, for each $||u||_\infty \leq \delta$, we have
$$||Au(t)||_\infty = \Bigg|\Bigg|\int_0^t e^{t-s} u(s) ds \Bigg|\Bigg|_\infty \leq e\delta = \epsilon.$$

To compute 
$$||A||_* = \sup_{||u||_\infty \leq 1} ||Au(t)||_\infty =\sup_{||u||_\infty \leq 1} \Bigg|\Bigg|\int_0^t e^{t-s} u(s) ds \Bigg|\Bigg|_\infty$$
it is not hard to see that the sup will be archived by taking $u \equiv 1$ and $t = 1$. From direct computation, we get
$$e \int_0^1 e^{-s} ds = e(- e^{-1} + 1) = e-1.$$

**(b)** Show $A$ is a injection.

Given that $||Au_1 - Au_2||_\infty = 0$, which means
$$ \sup_{t\in[0,1]} \Bigg|\int_0^t e^{t-s} (u_1(s)- u_2(s)) ds\Bigg| = \sup_{t\in[0,1]} e^t \Bigg|\int_0^t e^{-s} (u_1(s)- u_2(s)) ds\Bigg| = 0,$$
by dropping out the non-zero $e^t$, for each $0\leq a\leq b\leq1$, we have
$$\Bigg|\int_a^b e^{-s} (u_1(s)- u_2(s)) ds\Bigg| = \Bigg|\int_0^b e^{-s} (u_1(s)- u_2(s)) ds\Bigg| -\Bigg|\int_0^a e^{-s} (u_1(s)- u_2(s)) ds\Bigg| \\= 0 - 0 = 0.$$
Since $e^{-s} (u_1(s)- u_2(s))$ is continuous, we must have $u_1 \equiv u_2$.

**(c)** Determine the range of $A$.

My claim is that the range of $A$ is $C^1([0,1]) \subset C([0,1]).$ Using product rule, we have
$$\frac{d}{dt}Au(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \Bigg[e^t \int_0^t e^{-s} u(s) ds\Bigg]\\ = e^t \int_0^t e^{-s} u(s) ds + u(t)$$
which is continuous.

Now let $f\in C^1([0,1])$, we want to find a $u\in C$ such that $Au = f$.
$$f(t) = e^t \int_0^t e^{-s} u(s)ds$$
$$f(t) e^{-t} =  \int_0^t e^{-s} u(s)ds,$$
differentiate 
$$f'(t) e^{-t} - e^{-t} f(t) = e^{-t} u(t)$$
$$u(t) = f'(t) - f(t).$$

Comment: To be 100% rigorous for part (c), you should prove that $Au$ is differentiable before computing $\frac{d}{dt}Au(t)$.

Comment: Good point, is there a better way to show the product of two $C^1$ function is differentiable other than calculating the differential limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the product rule in part (c), it suffices to show that

$$
F(t)=\int_0^te^{-s}u(s)ds
$$

is a differentiable function of $t$, since we know that $e^t$ is differentiable.  Depending on what you're "allowed" to use, this is simply a part of the fundamental theorem of calculus. If you cannot invoke FTOC, simply consider the difference quotient:

$$
\frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h} = \frac{1}{h}\int_{t}^{t+h}f(s)ds
$$ where $f(s)\in C[0,1]$. As $h\rightarrow 0$, the above clearly converges to a limit (why?)

With this small justification, you can proceed with the product rule.  The rest of your arguments look good (though I didn't inspect them as closely).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I think I can use the fact that $\int_a^x f$ is differentiable in $x$ given $f$ is integrable. Could you also take a quick look at part (a) and (b) as well? Thanks again!

Comment: The rest looks good.  For (a) it's always good to show that for _all_ $u$ with $\|u\|_\infty\leq 1$, we have $\|Au\|_\infty\leq\|A\|_*$ (simple string of inequalities).  Even if you see what the norm is or can compute it, it's still good to prove that it satisfies the correct inequality.